# Gallery Automatic Scrolling Issues in Android

Tags: android, android-gallery, baseadapter

I have been playing with Gallery View for sometime now and I have the basic stuff up and running. However, I have a problem with scrolling. I have tried to search in google and did not get a simple solution to this problem. I am loading images using a Base Adapter and once done, I need to move to a particular position(read auto scroll). The problem that I am facing is that, let's say I have 50 images loaded in the gallery and I want to move to the 30th position, I would just need to call gallery.setSelection(30) and I should be done. This works only when called from a button click. However, I want the same to be done on the activity load itself. Once I bind the the BaseAdapter with the gallery, I am not able to find out when exactly the binding is completed. I would appreciate any help on this. This is how I am binding the adapter.

```
        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.wpGallery);
    ImageAdapter imgAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gallery.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
```

I want to move to the given position and also trigger the onClickEvent once it has moved to that position.

Comment: what happens when you call gallery.setSelection(30) immediately after gallery.setAdapter(imgAdapter);?  I don't think setAdapter goes off on a separate thread, so, it should block until it's done, shouldn't it?

Comment: Strange, earlier it used to crash. Now it's moving to that position but the onclick event is not getting triggered. Any idea ? Thank You for the reply. Appreciate it.

Comment: setSelection doesn't fire the click event... it just sets the selection. I think you can provoke the click manually but can't look it up now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work. But its worth a try.

Put this code in onCreate

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = gallery.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        gallery.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO.

    }
});
```

OnGlobalLayoutListener is called after the viewgroup is laid out on the screen. You should be able to do setSelection here.

Comment: I will try this out once I get the above stuff working. Thank You for the reply @blessenm